# Does True Seeing automatically detect the illusions from Weird?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw, illusion

The [*weird*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/weird) spell creates illusions in the minds of those it is cast upon (unless they make their save).

The [*true seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) spell gives truesight, which grants the automatic detection of visual illusions and saves against them automatically succeed.

Do the illusions created by *weird* qualify for this though?

The illusions the spell creates are visible to the targets, but only to them. They aren't visible in the classic sense like those produced by certain other illusion spells like *minor illusion*.

Comment: Is the *true seeing* spell specifically important? Since it's truesight in general that grants those benefits, you could simplify this by asking directly about truesight and simply stating that the *true seeing* spell is one way for a PC to get it.

Comment: Related: [What counts as a “visual illusion” for a character that has Truesight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122186/what-counts-as-a-visual-illusion-for-a-character-that-has-truesight), [How can Illusion Magic be effective against True Sight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109954/how-can-illusion-magic-be-effective-against-true-sight)